# Are there any solid way to view/delete online icloud keychain?

Tags: icloud, keychain

#### Background

I want to empty the items in the online keychain. I've tried many different methods, but none work so far. Whenever I think I deleted an item, the moment I sync with a new device the same item appears again. As there is no web GUI to work with the online keychain directly I have no way of confirming that an item is actually deleted.
Google searches have not helped me either.

#### Attempts

I have tried to:

- delete all keychains locally when the sync is on in all Apple devices
- delete the contents of the iCloud keychain
- enable/disable sync
- sign in/out of my iCloud account
- log in/out of my devices

But magically, when I configure a new apple device and login my apple id, all my old keys in the keychain store are synced and downloaded again to my new device.

#### Question

How can I ensure the online keychain is empty? Are there any solid way to do that?
Are there any open source apps which can manage the online iCloud keychain?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the ***contents*** of the iCloud keychain with the Keychain Access app? The iCloud keychain contains the items that are stored in iCloud and synchronized across your devices. To delete its contents, launch Keychain Access, select iCloud on the left pane, press Command-A to select all items and select Edit>Delete.

Comment: @jaume thanks a lot for your reply. Yeah, I tried that. That is the first thing I tried. But it doesn't work. As what I said in the question, It's not a solid way. After deleting them, I can not guarantee they are deleted or not. In a new device when I login, all old keys will be back again.

Comment: That should definitely delete them. From https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/icloud-keychain-information-safe-mac-mh43699/11.0/mac/11.0: "Removing credit card information or account names and passwords in Safari (or with Keychain Access) deletes them from your macOS keychain and from your iCloud Keychain." **The other possibility is to disable iCloud Keychain on all your devices**. From https://support.apple.com/HT204085: "If you don't choose to keep the [iCloud Keychain] information on at least one device, your Keychain data will be deleted from your device and the iCloud servers."

Comment: I've also found that "Removing ... account names and passwords in Safari (or with Keychain Access) deletes them from your macOS keychain and from your iCloud Keychain." isn't so - they come back.  Talking to Apple now about this.  Wish I could find/turn on/view sync logs.

Comment: Sync turned off (by itself, it seems-no apparent reason) and now I'm worried what will happen when I turn it on on a system that is quite out of sync (by >100 passwords of >1000).